# How to implement a CheckBox's onTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-widget

How do you implement this `onTouchEvent`? It should fire when the user checks or unchecks the `CheckBox` widget.

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(activity);
checkBox.setText("Don't present me information again.");
checkBox.onTouchEvent(.....);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CheckBox widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) (and any other widget that extends [CompoundButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html)) has a method [setOnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29), which is the bit you're lacking (you probably don't want to use [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) in this case).

This example should replace the final line of code in your snippet:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if ( isChecked ) {
      // do some stuff
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need in your case is [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29)

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this,"CheckBox is Checked ..",3000).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this,"CheckBox is Unchecked ..",3000).show();
        }

    }
});
```